# Can't get data from Essbase

Tags: olap, olap4j, essbase, oracle-olap

I'm new at OLAP services.
I want to get data from Essbase using olap4j.
I'm sending this request:

```
SELECT {[Year].[Jan]} on COLUMNS from [Demo.Basic]
```

and get an error that database Basic does not exist:

```
XMLA provider gave exception: 
<SOAP-ENV:Fault>
<faultcode>
    XMLAnalysisError.1051032
</faultcode>
<faultstring>
    <![CDATA[Cannot open cube view. Essbase Error(1051032): Database Basic does not exist]]>    
</faultstring>
<faultactor>
    XML for Analysis Provider for Essbase
</faultactor>
<detail>
    <Error Description="Cannot open cube view. Essbase Error(1051032): Database Basic does not exist" ErrorCode="1051032" HelpFile="" Source="XML for Analysis Provider for Essbase ">
    </Error>
</detail>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault>
```

Actually this database exists and works (http://grab.by/AqKU).
Also my code works fine with other OLAP services (e.g. Mondrian).

Can you please help me with this issue? Thanks!

Comment: It would help to add the exact error message you got

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing the MDX code yourself? You might try a couple of variants on the syntax:

```
SELECT ({[Measure]}) ON COLUMNS FROM Demo.Basic
WHERE ([Year].[Jan], [Location].[Seattle], [Scenario].[Actual])
```

Don't worry about the specific members I used here, but in particular you might try moving the FROM clause to after ON COLUMNS and try not using the brackets.